# SugarORM not working

Tags: android, sugarorm

So, I'm new to this and I'm trying to implement SugarORM to create a database because it's suppose to be easier.
I've followed every step of the tutorial and adapted it to what I want to do in my app but whenever I try to save something into the database, the app crashes and goes back to the previous activity. 
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I want to save 5 inputs into the database and be able to delete by inputing their name (which will also be stored in the database).

Here is the logcat:

```
09-25 15:00:29.909 18121-18121/com.example.cabr.teste E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
09-25 15:00:29.911 18121-18121/com.example.cabr.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.cabr.teste, PID: 18121
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SUGAR_ORM (Sqlite code 1): ,
  while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO SUGAR_ORM(ID,SIMULT,POTENCIA,QUANTIDADE,EQUIPAMENTO,HORAS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?),
  (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:925)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:536)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1725)
      at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:266)
      at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:360)
      at com.example.cabr.teste.Main14Activity$16.onClick(Main14Activity.java:417)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6577)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
09-25 15:00:29.919 512-893/? E/logserver: imonitor_add_dynamic_path, path:/data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1506348029917.txt
09-25 15:00:29.923 1374-11353/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
09-25 15:00:30.082 1374-11624/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
09-25 15:00:30.132 1374-11619/? E/Process: isHighLoadProcess: get cpu failed
09-25 15:00:30.736 18416-18447/com.example.cabr.teste E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 0
09-25 15:00:30.741 18416-18447/com.example.cabr.teste E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 34359738371
09-25 15:00:30.742 18416-18447/com.example.cabr.teste E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 240518168576
09-25 15:00:30.743 18416-18447/com.example.cabr.teste E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 68719476736
09-25 15:00:30.745 18416-18447/com.example.cabr.teste E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 1
```

And my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main14);

    final TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);

    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
    ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
    ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview4);
    ImageView imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview5);
    ImageView imageView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview6);
    ImageView imageView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview7);
    ImageView imageView8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview8);
    ImageView imageView9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview9);
    ImageView imageView10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview10);
    ImageView imageView11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview11);
    ImageView imageView12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview12);
    ImageView imageView13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview13);
    ImageView imageView14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview14);
    ImageView imageView15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview15);
    ImageView imageView16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview16);

    final TableLayout tableLayout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);

    final ScrollView scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main9Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    imageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.televisao2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.televisor));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sistemasom2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.sistemasom));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.leitordedvd2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.leitordvd));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.consoladejogos2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.consolajogos));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.aspirador2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.aspirador));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.arcondicionado2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.arcondicionado));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lampada2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.lampadas));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.computadorportatil2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.computadorportatil));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.aquecedoraoleo2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.aquecedoreletr));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ventoinha2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.ventoinha));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.desumidificador2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.desumificador));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ferroeletrico2);
            textView12.setText(getString(R.string.ferroeletrico));
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scrollView1.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
        }
    });

    imageView16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Marque a caixa se utiliza este equipamento em simultâneo com outros equipamentos.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String equipamento, tipohoras, periodo;
            Integer potencia, quantidade, simult;
            Double quanthoras;
            Double horas = 0.0;

            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            equipamento = textView12.getText().toString();
            potencia = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
            quantidade = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            quanthoras = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());
            tipohoras = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            periodo = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            simult = 0;

            if (potencia==0){
                if (equipamento.equals("Televisor")){
                    potencia = 90;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Sistema de Som")){
                    potencia = 150;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Leitor de DVD")){
                    potencia = 195;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Consola de Jogos")){
                    potencia = 140;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Aspirador")){
                    potencia = 600;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ar Condicionado")){
                    potencia = 1400;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Lâmpadas")){
                    potencia = 10;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Computador Portátil")){
                    potencia = 65;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Aquecedor Elétrico")){
                    potencia = 1500;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ventoinha")){
                    potencia = 80;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Desumidificador")){
                    potencia = 150;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ferro Elétrico")){
                    potencia = 1000;
                }
            }

            if (quanthoras==0){
                if (equipamento.equals("Televisor")){
                    horas = 5.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Sistema de Som")){
                    horas = 8.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Leitor de DVD")){
                    horas = 3.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Consola de Jogos")){
                    horas = 3.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Aspirador")){
                    horas = 1.04;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ar Condicionado")){
                    horas = 8.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Lâmpadas")){
                    horas = 5.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Computador Portátil")){
                    horas = 8.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Aquecedor Elétrico")){
                    horas = 4.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ventoinha")){
                    horas = 6.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Desumidificador")){
                    horas = 4.0;
                }
                if (equipamento.equals("Ferro Elétrico")){
                    horas = 1.0;
                }
            } else {
                if (periodo.equals("dia")){
                    if (tipohoras.equals("min")){
                        horas = quanthoras/60;
                    }
                    if (tipohoras.equals("h")){
                        horas = quanthoras;
                    }
                }

                if (periodo.equals("semana")){
                    if (tipohoras.equals("min")){
                        horas = (quanthoras/60)/7;
                    }
                    if (tipohoras.equals("h")){
                        horas = quanthoras/7;
                    }
                }

                if (periodo.equals("mês")){
                    if (tipohoras.equals("min")){
                        horas = (quanthoras/60)/30.42;
                    }
                    if (tipohoras.equals("h")){
                        horas = quanthoras/30.42;
                    }
                }
            }

            SugarORM sugarORM = new SugarORM(equipamento, potencia, quantidade, horas, simult);
            sugarORM.save();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"O equipamento foi adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            String equipamento;
            equipamento = textView12.getText().toString();

            SugarORM sugarORM = SugarORM.findById(SugarORM.class, 1);
            sugarORM.delete();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"O equipamento foi removido com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

And the SugarORM class:

```
public class SugarORM extends SugarRecord {
String equipamento;
Integer potencia;
Integer quantidade;
Double horas;
Integer simult;

public SugarORM(){

}

public SugarORM(String equipamento, Integer potencia, Integer quantidade, Double horas, Integer simult){
    this.equipamento = equipamento;
    this.potencia = potencia;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
    this.horas = horas;
    this.simult = simult;
}
```

}

And the manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="notes.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.example.cabr.teste" />
    <activity android:name=".Main10Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main4Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main5Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main6Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main7Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main8Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main9Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main11Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main12Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main13Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main14Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main15Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main16Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main17Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main18Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main19Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main20Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your declaration line from:

```
public class SugarORM extends SugarRecord
```

to

```
public class SugarORM extends SugarRecord<SugarORM>
```

If all else fails, increment your VERSION setting in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that SugarORM can't find the table as mentioned at your log `no such table:`. Try to delete the application and rerun it or try to call the `sugarDB.onCreate()` at the launch activity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not change the version of your database in the AndroidManifest.xml. Every time you change something in your code (SugarORM in this case) you need to update the version in your Manifest. Otherwise it wil not update your database and you will get this error.

The same goes for changing names of attributes, then the error will be: no such column.

```
<meta-data  android:name="VERSION"  android:value="2" />
```